# js regex backwards compatibility of flags

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

I have a some regex that works perfectly when running inside up-to-date browsers.  It is of the following form:

```
var re = new RegExp(/(somePattern)/,'g');
```

It throws an error on older versions of chrome, the error is that:

> "can't supply flags when constructing one RegExp from another"

Per the documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

> Starting with ECMAScript 6, new RegExp(/ab+c/, 'i') no longer throws a TypeError ("can't supply flags when constructing one RegExp from another") when the first argument is a RegExp and the second flags argument is present. A new RegExp from the arguments is created instead.

I don't exactly understand what that means.  How can I alter the regex above to avoid the error?

Comment: Exactly how old would this Chrome need to be to do this? If it's 1yr+ old I'd ask why you need support for it.

Comment: I cannot track down the exact Chrome release where the support for this ES6 features was added. They have been adding features over the last year, so my guess would be that the support came in perhaps six months ago. Most companies and apps have a policy of only supporting three back versions of self-updating browsers. However, IE support is a different matter. There are various hacks out there, including some here on SO, such as stringifying the regexp, modifying the string, and then `eval`'ing it back.

Comment: Supporting v43.  Not my choice: the industry I work in does not use best practices for supporting technology.  I have a specific large client needing compatibility on this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are already using a regex literal.

```
var reg = /abc/g;
```

That's a valid regular expression.

If you were to use the constructor (don't, unless you have good reason to), you should be passing it a string, and not a regex.

```
new RegExp("abc", "g");
```

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score -1):

The error message means that once a regexp is created you can't change the flags. What you're doing is basically:

```
new RegExp(new RegExp('(some pattern)'),'g');
```

Which throws the error.

What you should do instead is:

```
var re = new RegExp('(some pattern)','g');
```

or

```
var re = /(some pattern)/g;
```

Comment: @torazaburo: Yes, that's what it means. Note that new browsers won't even throw the error to saying that only browsers that throw the error mean that is tautology

Comment: Changed the English to clarify the meaning

Comment: You're confusing two related but different things. No, you can't change the flags for an existing regexp. What this is about is that you can't specify flags when using the `RegExp` constructor as a **copy constructor** (or at least, couldn't until ES6, which explicitly now supports this).

Comment: @torazaburo: That's what my answer is saying. Only in different words. Also, both the "different" things you're talking about are exactly the same thing for all intents and purposes. What can possibly be an example of "changing the flags of an existing regexp" if not by "using the RegExp constructor as a copy constructor (and supplying new flags)". Do you mean that the new behavior can only add but not remove flags? That's still changing the flags (albeit in only one direction)

Comment: For some reason, I still get the same error despite removing the constructor and writing it as suggested. This only happens when running it in android.

Comment: I even removed the regex just to see if anything different happened but the error persists... It's like something is stuck in android